# Retrive data untill it matches the next regular expression pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have error log data retrieved from the server and it is in the below format:

**text file:**

```
2018-01-09 04:50:25,226 [18] INFO messages starts here line1 \n   
    line2 above error continued in next line  
2018-01-09 04:50:29,226 [18] ERROR messages starts here line1 \n  
    line2 above error continued in next line  
2018-01-09 05:50:29,226 [18] ERROR messages starts here line1 \n 
    line2 above error continued in next line
```

I need to retrieve error/informational messages along with date timestamp.

Have written below code in python and its working fine if error messages are in only one line but its not working properly if same error logged in multiple lines(its giving only one line as output in this case but I need next line also if that belongs to same error).

It would be helpful if you provide any solution/idea.

Below is my **code**:

```
 f = open('text.txt', 'r', encoding="Latin-1")
 import re    
 strr=re.findall(r'(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})(\,\d{1,3}\s\[\d{1,3}\]\s)(INFO|ERROR)(.*)$', f.read(), re.MULTILINE)
 print(strr)
```

Above code giving output as :

> [('2018-01-09 04:50:25',',226 [18]', 'INFO','messages starts here
>   line1'),('2018-01-09 04:50:29',',226 [18]', 'ERROR','messages starts
>   here line1'), ('2018-01-09 05:50:25',',226 [18]', 'ERROR','messages
>   starts here line1')]

where as I expect output as

> [('2018-01-09 04:50:25',',226 [18]','INFO','messages starts here line1
>   line2 above error continued in next line' ),('2018-01-09
>   04:50:29',',226 [18]','ERROR','messages starts here line1 line2 above
>   error continued in next line' ),('2018-01-09 05:50:29',',226
>   [18]','ERROR','messages starts here line1 line2 above error continued
>   in next line' )]

Comment: I don't think if you need regex for this task. Just concatenate each the odd lines to their next.

Comment: @Kasramvd I need to know which is my next error hence i have used regex pattern and also there can be multiple lines for each error , not necessarily just two lines

Comment: You explicitly match against the end of a line (`$`) in your regex. If you don't know how many lines a "log line" might be split over, or if you have multiple processes/threads writing to the log at the same time, this is probably too difficult to do using just regex.

Comment: If you have control over what produces the log, then changing that to not produce log messages containing newlines would be the best idea, as that causes problems for all sorts of things you might want to do with the log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex**: [`(\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2}\s\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2})(,\d+[^\]]+\])\s(INFO|ERROR)\s([\S\s]+?)(?=\r?\n\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2}|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/3Tc1TJ/5)

**Python code**:

```
import re

matches = re.findall(r'(\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2}\s\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2})(,\d+[^\]]+\])\s(INFO|ERROR)\s([\S\s]+?)(?=\r?\n\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2}|$)', text)
```

Output:

```
[('2018-01-09 04:50:25', ',226 [18]', 'INFO', 'messages starts here line1\nline2 above error continued in next line'), ('2018-01-09 04:50:29', ',226 [18]', 'ERROR', 'messages starts here line1\nline2 above error continued in next line'), ('2018-01-09 05:50:29', ',226 [18]', 'ERROR', 'messages starts here line1\nline2 above error continued in next line')]
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/kmLz01)

Comment: Thanks a lot:-) Its working fine for me!!!Could you please brief about logic behind regex that you did..so that it will be helpful for me as well as others!!

Comment: @Sriharsha I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Add \n in your regex :

```
(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})(\,\d{1,3}\s\[\d{1,3}\]\s)(INFO|ERROR)(.*\n.*)
```

Comment: This would fail if there was a single-line error message - you're assuming all of them would be two lines long.

Comment: Yes, you're right. In this example, there are always 2 lines.

Comment: ...or if some messages were split over more than two lines. Perhaps the OP can clarify the scope of the problem

Comment: @ElodieDellier Thanks,.but its not giving expected result .its displaying result till \n

Comment: @Sriharsha Replace (.*)$ by (.*\n.*)$. Sorry, I'm not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *lookahead* expression and search for matches between `<date1>` (included) and `<date2>` (excluded) structures. In your case every log record starts with a `<date>` structure. You also need to remove `$` since it matches new line in case of `re.MULTILINE`.

**EDIT**

You can do even better. Run line-by-line, as soon as you find a `<date>` structure. Start to collect a new log record till you will observe a new `<date>` structure. Concatenate log lines related to one record and do your `regex`. Move to the next record.

Comment: Catch here is error messages may contains date time stamp also

Comment: Sure, but I don't believe that it contains absolutely similar structure like: `2018-01-09 04:50:29,226 [18] ERROR`

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't quite as neat as you were hoping, but there's nothing to stop you from checking line-by-line and accumulating the error info as you go along:

```
import re

example = '''2018-01-09 04:50:25,226 [18] INFO messages starts here line1
    line2 above error continued in next line
2018-01-09 04:50:29,226 [18] ERROR messages starts here line1
    line2 above error continued in next line
2018-01-09 05:50:29,226 [18] ERROR messages starts here line1
    line2 above error continued in next line  '''

output = []

for line in example.splitlines():
    match = re.match(r'(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})'
                     r'(\,\d{1,3}\s\[\d{1,3}\]\s)(INFO|ERROR)(.*)',
                     line, re.MULTILINE + re.VERBOSE)
    if match:
        output.append(list(match.groups()))
    # Check that output already exists - in case of headers
    elif output:
        output[-1].append(line)
```

This returns

```
[['2018-01-09 04:50:25', ',226 [18] ', 'INFO', ' messages starts here line1', '    line2 above error continued in next line'], ['2018-01-09 04:50:29', ',226 [18] ', 'ERROR', ' messages starts here line1', '    line2 above error continued in next line'], ['2018-01-09 05:50:29', ',226 [18] ', 'ERROR', ' messages starts here line1', '    line2 above error continued in next line  ']]
```